# How to connect separate processes under the same project (jBPM)

Tags: workflow, jbpm

My team is new to developing these things and I came into a project that is defining an over-arching workflow using separate processes that are all defined under the same project. So it appears that right now the processes defined are all discrete units, and the plan was to connect these units together using inputs and outputs.

Based on the documentation it looks like the best-practicey way of doing this would be to define the entire, over-arching workflow using sub-process tasks.

So I wonder:

- Is the implementation we've started workable?

or

- Should I only have one process unit per one workflow, which defines sub-processes if the workflow is too complicated and has discrete parts?

Comment: It looks like the method we're using right now is actually the sub-process method, so I would assume that connecting disparate processes is actually done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to separate out certain parts of the process into its own process, and then call those from some sort of parent process.  The task you should use in the parent process is called reusable sub-process, or call activity.  It's absolutely fine to have multiple processes in the same project.